# Opsworks - after_restart deploy hook code conditional on layer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I have code in after_restart.rb which I would like to run only if the restart is occurring in the rails-app layer.  I have a delayed job custom layer as well, and this code should not run if the app is restarted on delayed job layer. Both layers are on the **same instance**.  I tried the suggestion of using `node[:opsworks][:instance][:layers]` but since it is the same instance, i get `["rails-app", "utillayer"]` for both deploys (again, both deploys are on same instance, one for rails-app other for delayed job named utillayer)

I am hoping that there is a way to identify which layer the deploy is occurring for and tie that to an if statement to run the code if the restart is in "rails app" layer

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Specific node json you're after is : node[:opsworks][:instance][:layers]

```
node_layers = node[:opsworks][:instance][:layers]
## layer must belong to either rails-app OR custom
if (node_layers.include?("rails-app") || node_layers.include?("custom"))
  // do stuff
end

## layer must belong to alteast rails-app 
if (node_layers.include?("rails-app") 
  // do stuff
end

## layer must belong to BOTH layer 
if  node_layers.include?("rails-app") &&  node_layers.include?("workers") 
  // do stuff
end
```

Comment: This works great if each layer is in a dedicated instances.  The use case i am challenged with is that it is one instance which is in two layers, e.g. it runs rails-app and utillayer (delayed job).  So the deploy happens on this instance twice, rails is restarted twice and the after_restart is called twice.  I want to be able to run different code based on which rails layer the restart is taking place for.  So your solution is perfect if the layers were on separate instance... Would love to hear your thoughts if the layers are on same instance.

Comment: The standard recipes of AWS will run if you're using their layer code. You can't prevent this UNLESS you're using your own infrastructure code. I will add some variations for you to checkout :)

Comment: Imran, thank you for your answer and update... Still no luck... Both after_restarts report node_layers to be ["rails-app", "utillayer"]  So there is no conditional logic i can use to make it do what i am doing...

Comment: You can try : chef-rewind. This has a handy function : UNWIND https://github.com/bryanwb/chef-rewind .